# Vaadin widgetset compilation failture

Tags: java, maven, vaadin

Im using *vaadin-maven-plugin:8.1.2* because I want to have different widgetset than default one. 
When I compile widgetset (by Vaadin eclipse plugin) I get this:

```
[INFO] No widgetsets found - generating AppWidgetset if necessary.
[INFO] Updating widgetset AppWidgetset
[INFO] Adding resource directory to command classpath: 
C:\Users\myUser\eclipse-workspace\jpex\src\main\resources
[INFO] Adding resource directory to command classpath: 
C:\Users\myUser\eclipse-workspace\jpex\src\main\resources
[INFO] Adding resource directory to command classpath: 
C:\Users\myUser\eclipse-workspace\jpex\target\generated-resources\gwt
[INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client version 8.1.2
[INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler version 8.1.2
[INFO] Widgetsets found from classpath:
[INFO]  org.vaadin.sliderpanel.WidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/org/vaadin/addons/vaadin-sliderpanel/2.0.0/vaadin-sliderpanel-2.0.0.jar!/
[INFO]  com.vaadin.DefaultWidgetSet in jar:file:C:/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/com/vaadin/vaadin-client/8.1.2/vaadin-client-8.1.2.jar!/
[INFO] Addon styles found from classpath:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Search took 10ms
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- vaadin-maven-plugin:8.1.2:compile (default-cli) @ jpex ---
[INFO] auto discovered modules [AppWidgetset]
[INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client version 8.1.2
[INFO] Using com.vaadin:vaadin-client-compiler version 8.1.2
[INFO] Loading inherited module 'AppWidgetset'
[INFO]    [ERROR] Unable to find 'AppWidgetset.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.298 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-28T14:31:51+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/448M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:8.1.2:compile (default-cli) on project jpex: Command [[
[ERROR] C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_141\bin\java -Xmx512M -Xss1024k -Dgwt.persistentunitcache=false com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler -logLevel INFO -style OBF -war C:\Users\myUser\eclipse-workspace\jpex\target\classes\VAADIN\widgetsets -localWorkers 8 -failOnError -XfragmentCount -1 -sourceLevel auto -gen C:\Users\myUser\eclipse-workspace\jpex\target\.generated AppWidgetset
[ERROR] ]] failed with status 1
```

First of all I would like to ask how can I force plugin to use this: `org.vaadin.sliderpanel.WidgetSet`? It's always trying to compile `com.vaadin:vaadin-client version`
AppWidgetset.gwt.xml is created automatically in target/generated-resources/gwt with generated inherits I actually want, but somehow plugin cant find it.

Here is my web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
  <display-name>jpex</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.vaadin.spring.server.SpringVaadinServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>UI</param-name>
        <param-value>com.myProject.jpex.ui.JpexUI</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
        <param-value>org.vaadin.sliderpanel.WidgetSet</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Build part from pom.xml

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>

                <configuration>
                    <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx512M -Xss1024k</extraJvmArgs>
                    <webappDirectory>${basedir}/target/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets</webappDirectory>
                    <draftCompile>false</draftCompile>
                    <compileReport>false</compileReport>
                    <style>OBF</style>
                    <strict>true</strict>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spend like few hours dealing with it, when it was just about putting generated AppWidgetset.gwt.xml file to src/main/resources.